# Creating grid of checkboxes

Tags: css

I want to create a grid of checkboxes ,

```
<ul class="checkbox-grid">
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="text1" value="value1" /><label for="text1">Text 1</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="text2" value="value2" /><label for="text2">Text 2</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="text3" value="value3" /><label for="text3">Text 3</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="text4" value="value4" /><label for="text4">Text 4</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="text5" value="value5" /><label for="text5">Text 5</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="text6" value="value6" /><label for="text6">Text 6</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="text7" value="value7" /><label for="text7">Text 7</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="text8" value="value8" /><label for="text8">Text 8</label></li>
</ul>
```

But to checkboxes to be under each other, (e.g 5 checkboxes under each other and then new column)

in this example

```
text1   text6
text2   text7
text3   text8
text4    ...
text5
```

i have tried something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/FmV9k/) but these are not under each others but next to each other , is something like that possible?

Answer (score 3):

Set this in CSS

```
.checkbox-grid {
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The is a simple CSS trick to solve your Problem.
[CSS Columns](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp)

So you can simply add

```
.checkbox-grid {
  -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
  column-count: 2;
}
```

To your css and remove `.checkbox-grid li`